# C++/QThread: Create a class that stores a fuction pointer to call a function outside the class with variadic parameters

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, c++11, macros

I'm stuck and looking for ideas for a C++/Qt problem. Wording the question is hard enough, but here I go:
I'm working on taking a model a customer developed in "some tool" that's too slow and converting it to c++ to speed up simulation time. In this tool, the customer was able to write functions in the tool's pseudo-language. Using macros I've been able to take their code from this other tool and have it be a c++ function running in its own thread, but I'm stuck when I need to implement a function with parameters.

Limitations are I'm using Qt's threading model, and C++11 (MSVC2019)

So for example, there are several different functions defined that need to be started in different threads. Here they are all shown as `static inline void` but the reality is they are all functions that do not return anything.

```
static inline void functionA(int one_, double two_)
{ /* something */ }

static inline void functionB(double one_)
{ /* something */ }

static inline void functionC(double one_, double two_, double three_)
{ /* something */ }

static inline void functionD()
{ /* something */ }
```

And I have a thread class to work with Qt's threading model. Because we have to account for several different types of wait conditions, sub-classing QThread

```
class FunctionThread : public QThread
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   FunctionThread(QObject *p_ = nullptr) : QThread(p_) {}
   ~FunctionThread()
   {
      mMutex.lock();
      mAbort = true;
      mWaitCond.wakeOne();
      mMutex.unlock();
      wait();
   }
   
   void run() override
   {
      // I need to call one of the functions above based on user's function code
   }
   
   void step()
   {
      // called each "step" of time through the model
      mWaitCondition.tryWakeOne();
   }
   
private:
   QMutex mMutex;
   ModelWaitCondition mWaitCondition; // subclass'd QWaitCondition
   int mWakeAt;
   bool mAbort;
   
   // void* mFuncPtr // function pointer set to one of the static inline functions?
   // what about params?
};
```

Because of Qt, I can't do any template-ing on FunctionThread. For the static functions at the beginning, I can macro them however I need to. But when I define FunctionThread, I do not know how many functions there are, or what each functions parameters are. It's all based on the customer's model code.
I've tried std::function, std::tuple, and `template <typename... Args>`, which do not work because of Qt's MOC requiring complete types.

I've tried a huge nasty macro to generate a unique thread class for each function with variadic/packed params, but I run into a problem when I try to call the function:

User code:

```
FUNCTION(functionA, int one_, double two_)
{
   // blah blah blah
   FUNCTIONRETURN
}
```

Class creation macro:

```
   #define FUNCTION(NAME_, ...)                    \
                                                   \
   class NAME_ : public QThread                    \
   {                                               \
      Q_OBJECT                                     \
                                                   \
   public slots:                                   \
      void step()                                  \
      {                                            \
         QMutexLocker locker(&mMutex);             \
         if (gCurrentSimStep == mWakeAt)           \
         {                                         \
            gWorkingThreads++;                     \
            if (!isRunning())                      \
               start(HighPriority);                \
            else                                   \
               mWaitCond.wakeOne();                \
         }                                         \
      }                                            \
                                                   \
   private:                                        \
   QMutex             mMutex;                      \
   ModelWaitCondition mWaitCond;                   \
   int                mWakeAt;                     \
   bool               mAbort;                      \
                                                   \
   public:                                         \
                                                   \
      NAME_(QObject *parent_ = nullptr) :          \
         QThread(parent_)                          \
      {                                            \
                                                   \
      }                                            \
      ~NAME_()                                     \
      {                                            \
         mMutex.lock();                            \
         mAbort = true;                            \
         mWaitCond.wakeOne();                      \
         mMutex.unlock();                          \
         wait();                                   \
      }                                            \
                                                   \
      void run() override                          \
      {                                            \
         runFunction(__VA_ARGS__)  /*crap*/        \
      }                                            \
                                                   \
   void runFunction(__VA_ARGS__)                   \
      {
   
   #define FUNCTIONRETURN }};
```

I've googled just about every `packed parameter` and `variadic parameter` phrase that I can think of.  Problem is I want a `C++ Class member variable is a function pointer that calls anonymous function` but everything I find is about function pointers to member functions, or else something requiring templates.

Comment: It's not clear whether your `FunctionThread::run()` needs to call some specific one of the user-functions (e.g. this-thread-should-always-call-`functionA()`) or needs to call any of them based on run-time choices. It's also not clear where the arguments for the calls to the user-functions should come from.

Comment: .. you might use four (or howevermany) `std::function`s with suitable template types, calling them as needed, or you might pass in a functor-object (something with `operator()`, then owning that in the thread and calling it like a function; your functor-objects can be polymorphic and call out to the relevant user-function.

Comment: when you `move to thread` your object `FunctionThread::run()` will call. you should add `moveToThread(this);` in your constructor . each time you create obj this will call `FunctionThread::run()`

Comment: you can create one `enum` and then you need one `switch` based on which type in enum user chooses, switch will decide which function should be called.

Comment: Sorry for never coming back and updating this. I was able to do what was needed using the new static `QThread::create()` [link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#create), which allows for variadic parameters. I first overlooked it because it said it required C++17 (and I specifically use `CONFIG += c++11` for another library in the project). But apparently msvc2019 passes whatever checks Qt needs to implement this, so I guess I got lucky!

Answer (score 0):

`QThread::create(Function &&f, Args &&... args)` works with the compiler settings being used.